# Change the row if the primary key is inside second table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

[image]

I want to change the orders state to shipped if the order_no is inside the today shipped  table using sql in query. (i using ms accsess)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `where` clause.  For instance:

```
update orders
    set State = 'shipped'
    where order_no in (select ts.order_no from todayshipped as ts);
```

You might want to add `and State <> 'shipped'` to avoid updating already shipped rows.

For performance reasons, I often suggest `exists` instead:

```
update orders
    set State = 'shipped'
    where exists (select 1
                  from todayshipped as ts
                  where ts.order_no = orders.order_no 
                 );
```

This can easily take advantage of an index on `todayshipped(order_no)`.